# Flex 3.5 and Air 2.0 beta 2: Opening a *.cmd file

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Using Adobe Air 2.0 beta 2 I want to open a cmd file when the user clicks on a button, but I get `"Error #3001: File or directory access denied"`.

the code:

```
<mx:Button width="200" height="50" click="OpenFileHandler()"/>

<mx:Script>

private function OpenFileHandler():void
{
   var file:File = new File("C:\\OpenIE.cmd");
   file.openWithDefaultApplication();
}
```

The directory it's accessible and the file exist. Does adobe Air 2.0 beta 2 have a restriction when opening a cmd file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limitations on what can be opened with openWithDefaultApplication in a typical AIR 2 application.  Refer to [the asdoc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#openWithDefaultApplication()) for the complete list.  If you use a native installer for the application then the limitations do not exist and you can also use the [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) API.